# Ant can't find Javac. No matter what I do it always claims JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"

Tags: java, ant, java-home

...and that's wrong.

Here's the error I get:

**BUILD FAILED
C:_TraderPlatform\Clients\Open\Open\Java\Applets\PPDataTransporter\nbproject\build-impl.xml:338: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:_TraderPlatform\Clients\Open\Open\Java\Applets\PPDataTransporter\nbproject\build-impl.xml:158: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"**

I've set an environment variable called JAVA_Home to point to: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12"

Javac.exe is definitely in **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin**

I've got %JAVA_HOME%\Bin in my PATH variable.

I've mucked around with the various 'JavaHome' settings under HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft and I'm now utterly stuck.

All I wanted to do was build a Java applet from the command line using the build.xml that netbeans had knocked up for the project.

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: what is the result of echo %JAVA_HOME% ?

Comment: er...it's just returning %JAVA_HOME%.

Just checked and it's definitely in there as an environment variable in user variables and system variables

Comment: Did your environment variable include " characters?  It should have them because of the space as in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well ANT now works.

What did I do?

I removed it from c:\program files and 'reinstalled' it into "c:\ant"

Seems like it doesn't like non 8.3 filenames or directories.

Funnily enough I did this only because I misread the part of the manual that suggested ANT shouldn't be in non 8.3 style locations on 95/98/ME.  I didn't spot the OS reference and gave it a go.  I'm running Vista.

Oh well...

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: I think this can work if you use a 8.3 file name for ANT_HOME e.g. `C:\Progra~1`. *Installing Ant in a **short**, 8.3 path such as C:\Ant* is a good practice though as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

In eclipse set the installed JRE setting to the JDK - in the project (project properties -> Java Build Path-> Libraries), or global default in preferences (Java->Installed JREs). The eclispe setting is stronger than the system variable.

Answer (score 2):

Just include tools.jar on the ant classpath, wherever it is installed.

Comment: I was getting the same problem in eclipse, where i was using an ant plugin. I could not find any mistakes in the JAVA_HOME. I was looking at the property page for ant where it saud that tools.jar is required on the classpath for ant. I did that and the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the variable name is **JAVA_HOME** all uppercase. Also, run path from the command line and ensure that the path statement has the correct value for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: it's there all in upper case and PATH returns the right values

Comment: On Windows, Environment variables are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

What build process are you running?  Is one of the build scripts setting `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score -1):

OK, guys, for Windows 7 it needs the JAVA_HOME as a Windows Environmental Variable, I've also added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\ and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin to PATH, restarted Eclipse, now it works.... Well I have other problems though :D