# How to specify Eclipse's java.home setting for Ivy/Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy

When running an ivy resolve via IvyDE in Eclipse, which contains a packager.xml that executes a javac ant task, I get the following:

> Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the
>   classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not
>   point to the JDK. It is currently set
>   to "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre"
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:108)

In eclipse.ini I have

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw.exe
```

and in Help - About Eclipse - Installation Details - Configuration I see

```
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre
```

How can I make java.home point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse uses its own javac implementation internally. Therefore for most of the purpose you just need a compatible JRE. But javac task in ANT considers the JAVA_HOME or check for the local `path` variable. On windows machine as temporary fix you can do:

`Open a command prompt`
then type
`SET path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\;%path%` hit enter
then type
`<eclipsehome>\eclipse.exe`

Now any process spawned from your eclipse will have your JDK version in the path variable.

for a permanent solution..
1. `go to advance system setting`
2. select `advanced` tab
3. select `environment variables`
4. modify the system `path` variable and JAVA_HOME (if required)

You can do the similar thing for *nix system (just check how to set environment setting on them)

Hope this will work.

**UPDATE**

The PROJECT classpath isn't the same as the ANT classpath. To set up an Ant classpath, navigate to `window->preferences->ant->runtime` here check whether the `Global Entries` points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\lib\tools.jar` if not then add it. Normally it works in most of the cases where ant cries for javac task. if it fails then please check whether some other script is not resetting your JAVA_HOME variable and ANT `global entries` setting.

If IvyDE is not using the ANT bundled with eclipse as plugin (and referring to some standard installation) or if you have defined a environment variable like ANT_HOME then copy
`tools.jar` file from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\lib\` to `ANT_HOME\lib`.

Also check this previous SO post ( [Ant can't find Javac. No matter what I do it always claims JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063832/ant-cant-find-javac-no-matter-what-i-do-it-always-claims-java-home-is-c-prog) )

**UPDATE 2**
ok.. 
Check this page... http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/preferences.html

> Order of the classpath entries: By
>   default, the classpath container
>   entries are ordered by order of
>   declaration in the ivy.xml. When there
>   are many entries, it can be useful to
>   have them ordered lexically for
>   enhanced readability.

Is `tools.jar` present in `ivy.xml`? please check once.

Comment: I've correctly set the PATH and JAVA_HOME variables in the environment that executes Eclipse, but it doesn't take note of this. Only the -vm setting seems to influence the JAVA_HOME variable as used by the ant javac task run by IvyDE.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. My ANT classpath in Eclipse includes the tools.jar entry. I can run Ant build scripts with the javac task fine. Unfortunately it still doesn't work when I executing an ant javac task via IvyDE. Must be something to do with the way IvyDE is launching ant. I tried putting tools.jar in ANT_HOME\lib but that didn't help either.

Comment: @tukushan: hmmm.. ok ... i have updated my answer one more time... check whether it helps...

Comment: tools.jar is not in my ivy.xml, but I don't think it should be because my program doesn't require tools.jar. Maybe this might work but I don't know how to specify tools.jar in the ivy.xml.

Comment: @tukushan: Check out this page... http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/2.0.0.beta1/cp_container.html .. specially the `Edit the container configuration` section